# Android: Animate a line being drawn using canvas

Tags: android, jquery-animate, android-canvas

I have this custom View. In this custom view, I am drawing a line graph. I use a canvas and paint objects to draw the points of the line, as well as connect the points themselves using the drawLine() function of the canvas. This works fine, except I'm looking to animate the line being drawn.

I reckon I could break the drawLine call into multiple calls depending on the length of the line with a small delay between each call, but I feel like that would be resource-intensive and may affect performance when dealing with a large amount of points/lines. What do you guys think? Is there another way?

Any tips/hints are welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actual drawings will be performed on canvas.invalidate(). If you set time between your invalidate calls, for example, to 1/24 sec, you may have as many calls to draw your lines - you will have updates on the screen 24 times a second, like in a movie. Actual calls to draw lines will, as I think,not be a problem if you have hundreds or thousands lines.

Comment: How do you think the performance will be affected if I couple calls to drawLine() and invalidate together? For example, instead of calling drawLine once followed by invalidate (resulting in one instant drawing of the line), what would happen if I were to break down the drawing into a call to drawLine followed by invalidate, say, 10 times?

Comment: Not a good idea. You should call invalidate, when you need to actually show a person the results of updated canvas. A person cannot see updates more frequent, than 25 or, in best case 100hz,  you better make a timer which will call invalidate and not do it while drawing lines. Lines being written will be "cached" and will be drawn in "batches" every 25 or 50 or 100hz